# How to get a callback when Android NatveActivity is finished/exited in c++ JNI side?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, opengl-es-2.0

I have a native activity that runs a openGL window and have a JNI integrated where I have also registered calls so I can call c++ to Java and vice-versa.

Since I have to detach the native thread before I call finish on Java side, I cannot have a registered call from c++ to Java (as I have to release it, otherwise I get error reports from DalvinVM that native thread was not detached).

Can you tell me which function I can call on c++ side to "finish()" this native activity (some call that is provided by JNI) ? And what callback I can expect on Java side ? Will the OnDestroy get called ?

Answer (score 0):

So what has to be done is as you exit the main loop from the c++ side, the native-activity terminates. No need for complicated communication between c++ and Java.